# Castalia : Is it possible to connect a sink node to a router?

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I'm working on a e-health simulation project using Castalia simulator. I'm using the ValueReporting application scenario where all sensor nodes send their sampled medical data to a sink node. From there i want to send them to a remote hospital network. For that, i need to connect the sink node to an eventuel router. Is there any way i can achieve this ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What aspects of your system beyond the sink node you want to simulate? Generally, Castalia does not provide a good simulation environment for internet traffic. I imagine that your are talking about standard internet traffic. We cannot answer this question unless we know specifics of your system, and also your specific simulation/modelling needs.

Comment: @Thanassis I want to route the medical data from the sink node to a remote network (LAN) representing the hospital in my case. I know that IP networks are not supported by castalia. But is there any other alternative way i can achieve this ?